# Check if userinput contains substring

Tags: string, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, findstr

Hello please help me with this one!
I would like to check if the user input **URL** contains the defined **SUBSTRING** or not.
**If** yes I would like to *GOTO LONG* **else** *GOTO SHORT*

Thank you!

```
 @echo off


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

SET /P "URL= Input the link of the video: "



SET "SUBSTRING=?filter=archives&sort=time"




ECHO !URL! | FINDSTR /C:"!SUBSTRING!">nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO SHORT) ELSE GOTO LONG


:LONG
SET LINK=1
ECHO THIS IS A LONG LINK
ECHO "THE LINK NUMBER IS %LINK%"
ECHO !URL!
GOTO END



:SHORT
SET LINK=0
ECHO THIS IS A SHORT LINK
ECHO "THE LINK NUMBER IS %LINK%"
ECHO !URL!
GOTO END


:END
pause
```

Comment: Those four  `X` aren't actually in your code, are they? (also, considering you use `set /p`, I assume this is *not* `dos`)

Comment: @Stephan they are in the code because they work as "separators" if im right they prevent using & or ? as commands and yes this is a batch file, my bad

Comment: So you expect `XFINDSTR` is a valid command? Remove them - all four of them. And change to `SET "SUBSTRING=?filter=archives"` (note the position of the quotes)

Comment: I followed your steps and it worked then i saved it and it now gives me this error message `=timeThe system cannot find the file specified` IF I input this `https://www.twitch.tv/videos/578427308?filter=archives` I am very, very confused now

Comment: plus when i try to close it now gives a bunch of **"C^C^C^C^C^"** 's
Also I updated the code in the question if that helps

Comment: I figured out if the folder that this batch file is in has more batch files it just crashes all of them, strange anyways
it works now but it still gives an error line which says  `=timeThe system cannot find the file specified`  when I input `https://www.twitch.tv/videos/578427308?filter=archives&sort=time`

Comment: I just need a solution to "escape" using part of the inputs as commands

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So this is the working code. I will now mention the problems I had so others can learn from it

1. I **must** not enable `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`
2. I have to use quotes around variables for the **SET** command
3. Because I have `delayedexpansion` disabled I **must** use percentages instead of exclamation marks when I want to use a variable in a command later

Correct me if I am wrong but thats what I figured out with these guys' help and on my own by trial and error
I made this list and updated the code so if a newbie like me gets stuck they can have a look at this post.
Once again thank you guys!

```
@echo off

SET /P "URL=Input the link of the video:"

SET "SUBSTRING=?filter=archives"

ECHO "%URL%"|FINDSTR /C:"%SUBSTRING%">nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO SHORT) ELSE GOTO LONG

:LONG
SET LINK=1
ECHO THIS IS A LONG LINK
ECHO "THE LINK NUMBER IS %LINK%"
GOTO END

:SHORT
SET LINK=0
ECHO THIS IS A SHORT LINK
ECHO "THE LINK NUMBER IS %LINK%"
GOTO END

:END
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Using double quotes properly helps fix some of your problems.  There shouldn't be any need to use delayed expansion if you use quotes for the echo as well.

```
@echo off

SET /P "URL=Input the link of the video:"

SET "SUBSTRING=?filter=archives"

ECHO "%URL%"|FINDSTR /C:"%SUBSTRING%">nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO SHORT) ELSE GOTO LONG

:LONG
SET LINK=1
ECHO THIS IS A LONG LINK
ECHO "THE LINK NUMBER IS %LINK%"
GOTO END

:SHORT
SET LINK=0
ECHO THIS IS A SHORT LINK
ECHO "THE LINK NUMBER IS %LINK%"
GOTO END

:END
pause
```

Update Showing execution of batch file.

```
C:\Users\Squashman\Desktop>test.bat
Input the link of the video:https://www.twitch.tv/videos/578427308?filter=archives&sort=time
THIS IS A LONG LINK
"THE LINK NUMBER IS 1"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I just tried the code you gave me and for some reason if i input `httpexample` or `httpexample?filter=archives` it just freezes the cmd and why i try to close it it spams the command window with `C^` s

Comment: I figured out if in place my batch file from C: to D: it works any idea why is that?

Comment: it works now but it still gives an error line which says  `=timeThe system cannot find the file specified`  when I input `https://www.twitch.tv/videos/578427308?filter=archives&sort=time`

Comment: I just need a solution to "escape" using part of the inputs as commands

Comment: @kisgaras, I had no problems executing the code using the provided url.  See my output execution in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out if the folder that this batch file is in has more batch files it just crashes all of them, strange.

Comment: @kisgaras this code will not crash any other batch file.

Comment: I tested it 5 times throughoutly and I discovered that for me when I had 3 batch files in the same folder called asd.bat FINDSTR.bat and SUBSTITUTE.bat for some reason it made all of the batch files in that folder go crazy spamming the screen with `C^`'s and crashing. As soon as I separated the files it started to work again...

Comment: @kisgaras, so what do you think happens when you use the command `FINDSTR` and there is also a batch file named `FINDSTR` in the current working directory.  I will give you a hint.  **Don't ever name your batch files the same as another executable on your system unless you know how to work around it.**